# PHP download ready zip file which is placed on SFTP - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download, zip, sftp

So I'm trying to get ready zip file which is placed on my sftp host. I'm using wordpress.

To list zip files which are placed in specific folder I use this function:

```
<?php 
function getListOfZipNames() {
$base_dir = '/srv/data/web/vhosts/iuu.COMPANY.com/zips/';
$fileList = glob($base_dir.'*.zip',GLOB_BRACE);
return $fileList;}
 ?>
```

To get current URL name I use this function:

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
global $wp;
    $homeUrl = home_url($wp->request);
     $new_url = substr($homeUrl, 25, 100);
    return $new_url;
}
```

To compare it(it should be only downloaded file which has the same name as is URL(after domain))
f.g. https://company.com/asdsadfssd-345435-sdf23-dassdfds-.zip
I use this function:

```
function compareUrlWithZipName() {
$homeURL = getCurrentUrl();
    echo $homeURL;
    echo "<p></p>";
$listOfZipNames = getListOfZipNames(); 

    foreach($listOfZipNames as $filename) {    
    if(is_file($filename)){
       //      echo basename($filename);
       if(basename($filename) === $homeURL)
       {
      downloadFile($filename);
       }
        else {
         echo " NOT PAIR ";
        }
        echo " ";    
    }}
}
```

Above functions are fine. In compare I'm calling downloadFile and I cannot download any file. I tried a lot of methods but when I add:

```
header("Content-type: application/zip");
```

I received information on my webpage that:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvC8o.png)

Without this header it prints on my webpage:
[printedOnWebsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSMXF.png)

Here is the code which I try currently use to download zip file:

```
function downloadFile($filename) {   
      
$zipName = basename($filename);
$zipPath = $filename;

if (file_exists($zipPath)) {
    echo "exist";
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$zipName."\"");
          header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipPath));
        ob_end_flush();
    
    @readfile($zipPath);
    exit;
}else{
echo "doesn't exist";
}}
```

This file is placed on my sFTP server and this server will be automatically filled up by other zip's.
When user know URL then should has possibility to get only one zip with same name as URL. Download should be forced automatically.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: `echo "exist";` – do valid ZIP files usually start with `exist`? No? Then why is that the first thing _you_ are writing to the output stream, before the actual ZIP file contents?

Comment: _“I received information on my webpage that …”_ - that looks like a generic front end 500 error message - you need to go and check the error log in cases like this, to find out what the actual error was! (In this particular case, probably “headers already sent” … _because_ of that extra `echo` statement, that already created output.)

Comment: When I removed that header and it prints that zip file on my website then it start by "exist". I removed it now and it just start without. - same result.

Comment: You need those headers, to tell the browser that this is not plain text it should try and display directly.

Comment: Ok, so i will keep this header. Nów it will respond "that page is not reached". It should just redirect me to 404 page instead. - Where I'm calling those scripts.

Comment: Again, that looks like a 500 error …

Comment: So in this case I should look on permissions in this folder? Something else?

Comment: You should first of all go and check the error log.

Comment: I got something like this: RED: chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
YELLOW: VM1922:5551 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: That appears to be from your browser console. I am talking about the server-side error log.